# How to define path in anchor tag in blocks?

Tags: 6, uri

I'm working on localhost server and I added an anchor tag like below in block.

```
<a href="contactus">Contact</a>
```

In front page it goes to the path directly, but if it is other than front page, it added the current path also, for example

```
http://localhost/r4launch/content/contactus
```

It add the "content" in front of the path, then it return "**page not found**".

how to define path in anchor tag ? or is that anything I'm missing ?

Comment: Given that you have created a relative url (http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html#h-5.1.2) you really shouldn't be surprised by the resulting correct behavior.  I'd suggest looking into Drupal's `l()` functionality (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/6) to create links, especially if your base_path for Drupal isn't inside your webserver's main directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the non-aliased path, use `l()` to create your link. By non-aliased, I mean the Drupal system path (e.g. `node/235` instead of `about-us`). The non-aliased path for the Contact page is `contact`. This is really the best approach.

```
<a href="<?php print l('contact'); ?>">Contact</a>
```

But if you have an aliased path (e.g. `about-us` or `contact-us`), then use `base_path()`.

```
<a href="<?php print base_path() .'contact-us'; ?>">Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [base_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7) function to get the url with trailing slash '/'

Comment: Yes, 'base_path()' function work with 'php filter' text format.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a path alias defined for contactus (i.e. alias: contactus, system: node/3)?

I don't have a D6 system handy to look at, but in D7 you can check this at admin/config/search/path

If so, and assuming Drupal is at the domain root "/", then you just need to adjust your link from:

```
<a href="contactus">Contact</a>
```

to

```
<a href="/contactus">Contact</a>
```

And it should work everywhere on your site.

Comment: Your answer assumes that the Drupal site is located at domain root, which is not always the case.

Comment: True. But I would still verify what aliases exist to prevent confusion. I've edited the answer to make the assumption clear.

Comment: @kekkis it works for my case.